# Hard Integral with Numerical Approximation

Tags: numerical-integration

I'm rather new to Mathematica so there might be an easy solution but I couldn't find it in another forum. I have an integral that will probably require numerical approximation as Mathematica can't solve it directly.

My Code is

```
xFunction[x_] = (.01 + .3x)/(2*(2 + 3.2*x - 2.39*(x^2)))
$Assumptions = x <= 0.7
$Assumptions = x >= 0.3
MyIntegral = Integrate[(Tanh[Y]^2)*(xFunction[x] - Y)^(1/6), {Y, .3, x}]
```

Do I need to define x as a real number? The end goal is to take the values of x on 0.3<x<.7 and graph it which x as the independent variable on the x-axis and MyIntegral as the dependent variable on the y-axis. Y is just a dummy variable so it shouldn't matter. I'm sure it's just a few lines of code but I can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please include the full definition of Cfunction and C.

Comment: It is good practice to avoid using single capital letters as variable names in Mathematica (in particular, avoid `C`, since it has special meaning in Wolfram Language). Changing `C` to `c` and defining a test polynomial `CFunction[x_] := 3 x^2 - 5 x^3`, I do get a numerical result: `With[{c = 0.6},  NIntegrate[(Tanh[Y]^2)*(CFunction[Y] - Y)^(1/6), {Y, .3, c}]]`

Comment: Do you mean `(xFunction[x] - Y)` in the integrand and not `(xFunction - Y)`?

Comment: It has nothing to do with `x`. The integral `Integrate[(Tanh[Y]^2)*(Y)^(1/6), Y]` does not evaluate analytically.  Need to use Numerical integration as shown above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By this point, you have done most of the work already. Use `NIntegrate` instead of `Integrate` for numerical integration. I also changed `=` to `:=` in the definition of `xFunction`, and lastly, defined `MyIntegral` to be another function:

```
xFunction[x_] := (.01 + .3 x)/(2*(2 + 3.2*x - 2.39*(x^2)))
MyIntegral[x_] := NIntegrate[(Tanh[Y]^2)*(xFunction[x] - Y)^(1/6), {Y, .3, x}]
```

Now, this produces complex numbers for $x\in [0.3,0.7]$. So, instead of `Plot`, I use `ReImPlot`:

```
ReImPlot[MyIntegral[x], {x, 0.3, 0.7}]
```

and obtain[image]